# Custom mute/unmute button built with Vue mysteriously does not work in production but works perfectly in development

Tags: html, vue.js, nuxt.js

As the title suggests I'm having trouble figuring out why this mute/unmute button doesn't work. The code is below, but basically it's built with a v-hide directive that changes with an @click. When I use it on local host it works but when it is deployed on netlify it still mute/unmutes the video but the icon only changes once then is stuck on the unmute icon... I would appreciate any ideas as I've tried a bunch of different solutions with no success.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<template>    
<div class="flex flex-grow relative">
        <div @click="toggleMute" class="z-20 bg-white absolute bottom-4 right-4 text-black rounded-full bg-opacity-75">
          <div v-if="mute" class="sr-only">Unmute</div>
          <svg v-if="mute" class="h-12 w-12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><title>Volume Mute</title><path fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="32" d="M416 432L64 80"/><path d="M224 136.92v33.8a4 4 0 001.17 2.82l24 24a4 4 0 006.83-2.82v-74.15a24.53 24.53 0 00-12.67-21.72 23.91 23.91 0 00-25.55 1.83 8.27 8.27 0 00-.66.51l-31.94 26.15a4 4 0 00-.29 5.92l17.05 17.06a4 4 0 005.37.26zM224 375.08l-78.07-63.92a32 32 0 00-20.28-7.16H64v-96h50.72a4 4 0 002.82-6.83l-24-24a4 4 0 00-2.82-1.17H56a24 24 0 00-24 24v112a24 24 0 0024 24h69.76l91.36 74.8a8.27 8.27 0 00.66.51 23.93 23.93 0 0025.85 1.69A24.49 24.49 0 00256 391.45v-50.17a4 4 0 00-1.17-2.82l-24-24a4 4 0 00-6.83 2.82zM125.82 336zM352 256c0-24.56-5.81-47.88-17.75-71.27a16 16 0 00-28.5 14.54C315.34 218.06 320 236.62 320 256q0 4-.31 8.13a8 8 0 002.32 6.25l19.66 19.67a4 4 0 006.75-2A146.89 146.89 0 00352 256zM416 256c0-51.19-13.08-83.89-34.18-120.06a16 16 0 00-27.64 16.12C373.07 184.44 384 211.83 384 256c0 23.83-3.29 42.88-9.37 60.65a8 8 0 001.9 8.26l16.77 16.76a4 4 0 006.52-1.27C410.09 315.88 416 289.91 416 256z"/><path d="M480 256c0-74.26-20.19-121.11-50.51-168.61a16 16 0 10-27 17.22C429.82 147.38 448 189.5 448 256c0 47.45-8.9 82.12-23.59 113a4 4 0 00.77 4.55L443 391.39a4 4 0 006.4-1C470.88 348.22 480 307 480 256z"/></svg>
          <div v-if="!mute" class="sr-only">Mute</div>
          <svg v-if="!mute" class="h-12 w-12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><title>Volume On</title><path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M126 192H56a8 8 0 00-8 8v112a8 8 0 008 8h69.65a15.93 15.93 0 0110.14 3.54l91.47 74.89A8 8 0 00240 392V120a8 8 0 00-12.74-6.43l-91.47 74.89A15 15 0 01126 192zM320 320c9.74-19.38 16-40.84 16-64 0-23.48-6-44.42-16-64M368 368c19.48-33.92 32-64.06 32-112s-12-77.74-32-112M416 416c30-46 48-91.43 48-160s-18-113-48-160" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="32"/></svg>

        </div>
        <video id="video" ref="video" class="object-cover rounded-lg w-full h-full" src="/Jet_Token_Accelerate_1.mp4" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline=""></video>
    </div>
</template>

    <script>
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          mute: true
        }
      },
      methods: {
        toggleMute() {
          var vid = this.$refs.video
          vid.muted = !vid.muted
          this.mute = !this.mute
        },
      },
    }
    </script>
```

And the resulting mute button that successfully mutes and unmutes but which does not properly switch between the mute and unmute icon after the first click:
[image: picture of mute button muted]

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle the data `mute` first then pass that state to `vid.muted` so that the video and icon are in synced.

```
toggleMute() {
  var vid = this.$refs.video
  this.mute = !this.mute;
  vid.muted = this.mute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually setting the `<video>`'s `muted` property, you could just use the [`v-bind` directive](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) to bind the property to the component's `mute`:

```html
<template>
  <video :muted="mute"></video>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      mute: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleMute() {
      this.mute = !this.mute
    }
  }
}
</script>
```